# Search for value in all tables of a database

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have the following problem for which I’m trying to find an elegant solution.
The front-end shows a search input field. The user is allowed to enter any string. I want to send a request to the backend and get all entities which contain the entered value in any column. It is unknown in which table and which column the entered string can be found.
Example:
Entities: Human, Building, Planet
All of them have 15+ attributes. 
Now, the user enters the number 12 into the search field. I want the backend to find any entries in the database which contain the number 12 which could be a person’s shoe size or the street number the building is in and so on. 
As technologies for the backend, I’m using JPA (Hibernate) and a Postgres database. 
I’d like to implement that as generic as possible so I don’t have to modify anything if new tables or new attributes come along. 
What I already tried is getting all table names like that:

```
"select col.table_name from information_schema.columns col join information_schema.tables tab on tab.table_schema = col.table_schema and tab.table_name = col.table_name and tab.table_type = 'BASE TABLE' where col.table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')"
                + "group by col.table_name"
```

Since jpa querys use the Java class name instead of the table name, it’s no use tough. Same problem is for attributes. Using native querys to avoid this problem would make things even more complicated.
Is there any good solution to search the whole database for a specific value?

Comment: That's not really a suitable use case for a RDBMS (or JPA).

Comment: You can use a native query or stored procedure to search for this value. But it is really not a good idea, because depending on the size of your database that search can take ages. The user needs to narrow down the scope

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454). Doing a full table scan of every table in your database will never perform well once your program leaves the development lab and the database starts growing in size. What you're asking about is what **text searching** was invented to solve. Forget about building dynamic queries to do full table scans of every table in your database, and instead look into adding text search functionality to your database.